# reshape pandas DF to show all id

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
+------------+----+--------+
|    date    | id | number |
+------------+----+--------+
| 2022-05-02 | A  | 397177 |
| 2022-04-29 | A  |  53876 |
| 2022-04-29 | B  | 191214 |
| 2022-04-28 | A  |  75824 |
| 2022-04-28 | B  | 483860 |
| 2022-04-28 | C  |  51731 |
+------------+----+--------+
```

It is the result of a query on a database.
There are only 3 different ID possible (`A`, `B` or `C`), but it could very well be that there are no data for some ID on some day (e.g., 2nd of May there were no records found for `B` and `C`, on the 29th of April there were no records found for `C`).

In the end, I would like to *reshape* the dataframe in order to have all IDs for each day, even if the number is 0.

Expected output:

```
+------------+----+--------+
|    date    | id | number |
+------------+----+--------+
| 2022-05-02 | A  | 397177 |
| 2022-05-02 | B  |      0 |
| 2022-05-02 | C  |      0 |
| 2022-04-29 | A  |  53876 |
| 2022-04-29 | B  | 191214 |
| 2022-04-29 | C  |      0 |
| 2022-04-28 | A  |  75824 |
| 2022-04-28 | B  | 483860 |
| 2022-04-28 | C  |  51731 |
+------------+----+--------+
```

Is that possible in Python using pandas?

Comment: yes, there are many options, check the duplicate link ;)